# MVC 4 Error 404 on Created View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class CheckoutController : Controller
{

    ShoppingCartContext storeDB = new ShoppingCartContext();
    const string PromoCode = "FREE";

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
    {
        var order = new Order();
        TryUpdateModel(order);

        try
        {
            if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
            {
                return View(order);
            }
            else
            {
                order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
                order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

                //Save Order
                storeDB.Orders.Add(order);
                storeDB.SaveChanges();
                //Process the order
                var cart = Models.ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                cart.CreateOrder(order);

                return RedirectToAction("Complete",
                    new { id = order.OrderId });
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //Invalid - redisplay with errors
            return View(order);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Complete(int id)
    {
        // Validate customer owns this order
        bool isValid = storeDB.Orders.Any(
            o => o.OrderId == id &&
            o.Username == User.Identity.Name);

        if (isValid)
        {
            return View(id);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }

}
```

And I have created a View called `AddressAndPayment` under `Checkout`, so it goes to `localhost/Checkout/AddressAndPayment` but I only get a 404 error, even if I right click on the View and click on view in Page Inspector. I don't know why its not even showing the view when it is created.

Comment: How are you requesting `localhost/Checkout/AddressAndPayment`?  If it's not a `POST` request then there's no matching route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a corresponding `HttpGet` method, as your current one only accepts a `HttpPost` request. Add the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddressAndPayment()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Every action listens to `GET` requests by default, so the `HttpGet` attribute is redundant. Nonetheless your answer is correct, +1.

Comment: @HenkMollema Whilst true, you should get into the habit of decorating both `HttpGet` **and** `HttpPost` methods, otherwise in some cases you may end up hitting the `HttpGet` action on a `HttpPost` request (it will match the first one it sees). Spent hours debugging silly issues like that.